# Typescript module 0.9 vs 0.8

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript 0.9 lists one of the breaking changes as:

> The ‘module’ keyword no longer creates a type
>
> Description: In 0.9.0, a clearer distinction is made between roles of
>   namespaces, types, and values. Modules now contribute only to
>   namespaces and values and will no longer contribute a type.  Reason:
>   This simplification of the role of modules allow modules to now extend
>   classes and functions more easily.

Yet when I compile the modules sample:

```
module Sayings {
    export class Greeter {
        greeting: string;
        constructor(message: string) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        greet() {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        }
    }
}
var greeter = new Sayings.Greeter("world");

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet());
};

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

0.9.0 and 0.8.3 produce exactly the same output (except for some whitespace):

```
var Sayings;
(function (Sayings) {
    var Greeter = (function () {
        function Greeter(message) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        };
        return Greeter;
    })();
    Sayings.Greeter = Greeter;
})(Sayings || (Sayings = {}));
var greeter = new Sayings.Greeter("world");
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function () {
    alert(greeter.greet());
};
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

So where is the breaking change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules can no longer be used in place of types.

e.g. The following was valid in 0.8:

```
module Bar{
}

var foo:Bar;
```

It is not for 0.9

Try it on the [updated 0.9 playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20Bar%7B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0Avar%20foo%3aBar;%20//%20Error%20%20)